# How to redirect and pass URL parameters with htacccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string, mod-alias

How to redirect affiliate link and add tracking code?

I have an WordPress website. There is an affiliate link on home page. I redirect (cloak) this link with `.htaccess` Redirect:

```
Redirect 302 /go/besthost https://www.affiliatepanel.com/?id=12345
```

My website is on `example.com`.

Running ads I send URL Parameters

```
https://www.example.com?ad=adname&camp=cname&source=google
```

How to read URL parameters and add them to affiliate link so it should become

```
https://www.affiliatepanel.com/?id=12345&ad=adname&camp=cname&source=google
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please show us simply do mention from which url to which url you want to Redirect/Rewrite(in backend) in your question for better understanding of the question.

Comment: How does `/go/besthost` relate to your second example with URL parameters? "I redirect (cloak) this link" - there's nothing "cloak-like" about that _external redirect_.

Comment: I'm sorry. The link on my website is domain.com/go/besthost and I redirect it to affiliatepanel.com domain. I want to get URL parameters and pass then to affiliatepanel.com

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the URL parameters you'll need to use a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (redirect), rather than a mod_alias `Redirect` directive.

For example, if the request is `https://www.example.com/url-path?url-parameters` and you want to redirect this to `https://www.affiliatepanel.com/?id=12345&url-parameters` then you would do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^url-path$ https://www.affiliatepanel.com/?id=12345 [QSA,R=302,L]
```

The `QSA` flag (Query string Append) does the "magic" of appending the original query string (ie. "url-parameters") from the request on to the redirected URL.

If it wasn't for the fact you are adding a new query string (ie. `id=12345`) then you wouldn't have to do anything, since the query string is appended by default (as long as you don't add a new one).